# having issue installing React-native application(codacanyon script)

Tags: react-native, node-modules, npm-install, package.json

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\fiverr\Patient care online-doctor-consultation-with-multi-pharmacy-app\c2h_customer\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\build.gradle' line: 65
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-gesture-handler'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'kotlin-android'.
> Malformed \uxxxx encoding.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-gesture-handler'.

> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 50s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\fiverr\Patient care online-doctor-consultation-with-multi-pharmacy-app\c2h_customer\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\build.gradle' line: 65
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-gesture-handler'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'kotlin-android'.
> Malformed \uxxxx encoding.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-gesture-handler'.

> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 50s

```
at makeError (D:\fiverr\Patient care online-doctor-consultation-with-multi-pharmacy-app\c2h_customer\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at D:\fiverr\Patient care online-doctor-consultation-with-multi-pharmacy-app\c2h_customer\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (D:\fiverr\Patient care online-doctor-consultation-with-multi-pharmacy-app\c2h_customer\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\fiverr\Patient care online-doctor-consultation-with-multi-pharmacy-app\c2h_customer\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.`

i tried to install npm using command "npm install --force" becuase "npm install" was not working
now i am having issues and unable to resolve need the help